# Consistency levels in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

As per my complete analysis on Cassandra, I come up with the following chart, Could somebody say whether it is a perfect one, If something is wrong please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Defacing content if not the proper way to get your post removed.

Comment: remove this post @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one algorithm. That is :

```
RF > WC + RC
RF = Replication factor  
WC = Write consistency   
RC = Read consistency
```

Which means, if you design in such a way , where Replication factor is greater than the total summation of read consistency and write consistency , you need not to worry about data consistency.

For Example: If you have a data with RF = 3, WC= 2, RC = 1 , you may not get the updated data while reading. But if you make it WC = 2, RC = 2, there is a little chance of not getting updated data.

So, to determine consistency level, make decision according to necessity. But ensure that query is executed maintaining RF > WC+ RC .
You will get a detailed explanation here : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

Answer (score 1):

As I stated before - you do not need to take number of nodes in your cluster into account (als long your cluster has enough nodes for your replication factor chosen).

How many node failures a cluster can tolerate is only defined by replication factor and desired consistency level (you can seed that in your table). Also I suggest in almost all cases not to choose a consistency level of TWO or THREE as from my experience ONE or QUOURUM often fit enough and you can change replication factors on a running cluster without impacting application behaviour.

Did you notice that your recommendations are with one exception CL.QUROUM?

Last point - you should think how much consistency you really need.

Comment: I totally got your point, I am making a study so I need to consider all scenario :)